# Iterating through an integer 64 array prints incorrect values in R

Tags: r, bit64, integer64

Do `for` loop and `lapply` not inherently support `integer64` ?

```
> x <- as.integer64(c("100000000000", "10000000000000"))
> x
integer64
[1] 100000000000   10000000000000
> for(y in x) {print(y)}
[1] 4.940656e-313
[1] 4.940656e-311
> tmp <- lapply(x, function(y) {print(y)})
[1] 4.940656e-313
[1] 4.940656e-311
> for(i in 1:length(x)) {print(x[i])}
integer64
[1] 100000000000
integer64
[1] 10000000000000
> as.list(x)
[[1]]
[1] 4.940656e-313

[[2]]
[1] 4.940656e-311
> as.list(as.integer64(x[1]))
[[1]]
[1] 4.940656e-313
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a list and iterate over the list:

```
library(bit64)
z <- list(as.integer64("100000000000"), as.integer64("10000000000000"))

for(y in z) {print((y))}
#integer64
#[1] 100000000000
#integer64
#[1] 10000000000000

tmp <- lapply(z, function(y) {print(y)})
#integer64
#[1] 100000000000
#integer64
#[1] 10000000000000
```

or use `gmp` which works for `lapply`:

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(c("100000000000", "10000000000000"))

lapply(x, function(y) {print(y)})
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 100000000000
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 10000000000000
```

Comment: How does one use `paste` with lists of integer64 ? In that case, `bigz` might prove to be helpful !

Comment: Maybe try: `paste(lapply(z, as.character))`